# how to create base SAS Scheduler for every Hours

Tags: sas

I run some SAS queries in (Base SAS 9.4) every hour. I was wondering if there was any way I can schedule these to run on a certain TIME FOR every hours in a certain order? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: As @pinegulf mentioned, typically it's better to look into dedication scheduling solutions rather than use SAS itself as a scheduler.  Are you on PC SAS, or a SAS server (what OS?)?  Are you using Enterprise guide?  EG has some scheduling facilities (I think integrated with windows scheduler), and SAS BI server also typically has integrated schedulers (LSF or whatever).

Comment: I m using PC SAS in window 7 ,64-bit OS. It's BASE SAS 9.4. In base sas i m able to do scheduler job or not. Thanks

Comment: In Base SAS after you have a .sas file with your code that works when you batch submit it, you can use Win scheduler to schedule it.  So Win scheduler will run something like `C:\Program Files\...\sas.exe  -sysin "C:\....\MyProgram.sas"`.  Or a .bat file or whatever script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advice to utilize some other means of timing processes. (Such as cron tabs or Jenkins)

However here is something that might be of use.

```
%macro do_every_hour;
%do %while(1); /*Does not end, so be sure what you do....*/

    data time; /*When the loop begins, stored to dataset*/
        begin=datetime();
    run;

    %do_the_queries; /*Your own queries go here*/


    data time; /*How long did the queries take. */
        set time;
        end=datetime();
        time_remain=(60-(end-begin)) <>0 ; /*Calculate the time for sleep if you want every hour.  Make sure there are no negative values. */
        call symput("sleep_time", time_remain); /*Take the number to macro variable for clarity's sake.*/
    run;

    %sysfunc(sleep(&sleep_time)); /*Here we wait for the next round.*/

%end; /*Do loop end.*/
%mend do_every_hour;

%do_every_hour;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)