# sas query to schedule jobs

Tags: sql, database, sas, enterprise-guide

I have a job of running certain set of queries on daily basis to fetch data from my datbase. Queries are run on sas enterprise guide. 
So basically I need to automate this process.Please suggest some code so that automatically at a particular time of the day, these queries are automatically run and I get my data.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all your question is too broad and general. Have you researched and tried anything, if yes plz mention and show the code or specific problem?

Comment: Have you heard about `cron-job`? 

Please check out this document. [a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/)

Comment: Similar to question to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179523/how-to-create-base-sas-scheduler-for-every-hours

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Guide help for "Scheduling projects and process flows" describes the steps needed.

> ### Automating Projects
>
> #### Scheduling projects and process flows
>
> In SAS Enterprise Guide, you can use the Microsoft Windows Task Scheduler to schedule projects and process flows to run at a specified time or as the result of a system event. By default, when you open the Task Scheduler, a script is automatically created in SAS Enterprise Guide to run the project or process flow. When you schedule the project or process flow, the Task Scheduler creates a scheduled task that includes the script and the criteria that specify when the task should be run. The scheduled task is added to the project tree. 
>   Note You must save the project to your local computer before you can create a scheduled task.